# What hooks should I use for pre-login and pre-registration actions?

Tags: login, user-registration

I am adding cookie on login page using 'init' action-hook.

And than after login I check if this cookie exist in 'login_init' action-hook.

And also after user registration I check if this cookie exist in 'registration_errors' filter-hook.

**Do I use proper hooks for pre-login and pre-registration actions?**

code:

```
<?php

$securityprotection_send_brute_force_log_to_admin = true; // if true, than info about blocked brute-force attacks will be sent to admin email

$securityprotection_login_cookie_check = true; // if true, than cookie will be set on login screen and checked before login

$securityprotection_registration_cookie_check = true; // if true, than cookie will be set on registration screen and checked before registration



if ( ! function_exists( 'securityprotection_hooks' ) ) :

    function securityprotection_hooks() {
        add_action( 'init', 'securityprotection_set_login_cookie' );
        add_action( 'login_init', 'securityprotection_login' );
        add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'securityprotection_registration', 10, 3 );
    }

    securityprotection_hooks();


    function securityprotection_set_login_cookie() {
        global $securityprotection_login_cookie_check;
        if( $securityprotection_login_cookie_check ) {
            if( strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'GET' and !isset( $_COOKIE['wordpress_secprot_cookie'] ) ) {
                setcookie( 'wordpress_secprot_cookie', '1', time()+60*60*24*30, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN ); // set cookie for a month
                $_COOKIE['wordpress_secprot_cookie'] = '1';
            }
        }
    }


    function securityprotection_login() {
        global $securityprotection_send_brute_force_log_to_admin, $securityprotection_login_cookie_check;

        if( $securityprotection_login_cookie_check ) {
            if( strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == 'POST' and !isset( $_COOKIE['wordpress_secprot_cookie'] ) ) {

                if ( $securityprotection_send_brute_force_log_to_admin ) { // if sending email to admin is enabled
                    $securityprotection_admin_email = get_option('admin_email');  // admin email

                    if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) { //check ip from share internet
                        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) { // to check ip is pass from proxy, also could be used ['HTTP_X_REAL_IP ']
                        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                    } else {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    }

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info = '';
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'IP : ' . $ip . "\r\n";

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'HTTP_USER_AGENT : ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n";
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'REQUEST_URI : ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\r\n";
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'HTTP_REFERER : ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\r\n\r\n";
                    //$securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'SERVER_PROTOCOL : ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . "\r\n";
                    //$securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'REDIRECT_STATUS : ' . $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] . "\r\n\r\n";


                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'POST vars:'."\r\n"; // lets see what POST vars brute-forcers try to submit
                    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
                        $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= '$_POST['.$key. '] = '.$value."\r\n"; // .chr(13).chr(10)
                    }
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= "\r\n\r\n";



                    $securityprotection_message = '';

                    $securityprotection_message .= $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info; // post, cookie and other data

                    $securityprotection_message .= $securityprotection_message_append;


                    $securityprotection_subject = 'Login brute-force on site ['.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).']'; // email subject
                    @wp_mail( $securityprotection_admin_email, $securityprotection_subject, $securityprotection_message ); // send log info to admin email

                }

                // many brute-force attacks are waiting for redirect or WordPress login cookies
                // if we will fake redirect and login cookies than many brute-forcers will stop their attacks

                securityprotection_set_fake_login_cookies(); // set fake login cookies

                securityprotection_fake_redirect(); // fake admin dashboard redirect

            }

        }

    }

    function securityprotection_registration($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
        global $securityprotection_send_brute_force_log_to_admin, $securityprotection_registration_cookie_check;

        if( $securityprotection_registration_cookie_check ) {
            if( strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == 'POST' and !isset( $_COOKIE['wordpress_secprot_cookie'] ) ) {

                if ( $securityprotection_send_brute_force_log_to_admin ) { // if sending email to admin is enabled
                    $securityprotection_admin_email = get_option('admin_email');  // admin email

                    if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) { //check ip from share internet
                        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                    } elseif ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) { // to check ip is pass from proxy, also could be used ['HTTP_X_REAL_IP ']
                        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                    } else {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    }

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info = '';
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'IP : ' . $ip . "\r\n";

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'HTTP_USER_AGENT : ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n";
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'REQUEST_URI : ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\r\n";
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'HTTP_REFERER : ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\r\n\r\n";

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'POST vars:'."\r\n"; // lets see what POST vars brute-forcers try to submit
                    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
                        $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= '$_POST['.$key. '] = '.$value."\r\n"; // .chr(13).chr(10)
                    }
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= "\r\n\r\n";

                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= 'COOKIE vars:'."\r\n"; // lets see what COOKIE vars brute-forcers try to submit
                    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
                        $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= '$_COOKIE['.$key. '] = '.$value."\r\n"; // .chr(13).chr(10)
                    }
                    $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info .= "\r\n\r\n";


                    $securityprotection_message = '';

                    $securityprotection_message .= $securityprotection_message_brute_force_info; // post, cookie and other data

                    $securityprotection_message .= $securityprotection_message_append;


                    $securityprotection_subject = 'Registration brute-force on site ['.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).']'; // email subject
                    @wp_mail( $securityprotection_admin_email, $securityprotection_subject, $securityprotection_message ); // send log info to admin email

                    $errors = new WP_Error();
                    $errors->add( 'security_protection_error', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Security-protection registration error.' );

                    //securityprotection_set_fake_login_cookies(); // set fake login cookies
                    //securityprotection_fake_redirect(); // fake admin dashboard redirect

                }
            }
        }
        return $errors;

    }


endif; // end of securityprotection_hooks()


if ( ! function_exists( 'securityprotection_plugin_meta' ) ) :
    function securityprotection_plugin_meta( $links, $file ) { // add 'Plugin page' and 'Donate' links to plugin meta row
        if ( strpos( $file, 'security-protection.php' ) !== false ) {
            $links = array_merge( $links, array( '<a href="http://web-profile.com.ua/wordpress/plugins/security-protection/" title="Plugin page">Security-protection</a>' ) );
            $links = array_merge( $links, array( '<a href="http://web-profile.com.ua/donate/" title="Support the development">Donate</a>' ) );
        }
        return $links;
    }
    add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'securityprotection_plugin_meta', 10, 2 );
endif; // end of securityprotection_plugin_meta()



if ( ! function_exists( 'securityprotection_random_string_generator' ) ) :
    function securityprotection_random_string_generator( $readable = 0, $length = 32 ) {
        $random_string = '';
        if( $readable ){ // create readable random string like 'suzuki'
            $characters_b = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz';
            $characters_a = 'aeiouy';
            $ab = 'b';
            for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
                if( $ab == 'b' ){
                    $random_string .= $characters_b[ rand( 0, strlen( $characters_b ) - 1 ) ];
                    $ab = 'a';
                } else {
                    $random_string .= $characters_a[ rand( 0, strlen( $characters_a ) - 1 ) ];
                    $ab = 'b';
                }
            }
        } else { // create fully random string like 'q3WLtN'
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
                $random_string .= $characters[ rand( 0, strlen( $characters ) - 1) ];
            }
        }
        return $random_string;
    }
endif; // end of securityprotection_random_string_generator()


if ( ! function_exists( 'securityprotection_fake_redirect' ) ) :
    function securityprotection_fake_redirect() { // fake admin dashboard redirect
        //header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); // correct redirect
        $redirect_to = admin_url();
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to); // redirect the brute-force bot to admin section to emulate that the password is cracked and some brute-forcers stop their attacks after such redirect :)
        exit();
    }
endif; // end of securityprotection_fake_redirect()


if ( ! function_exists( 'securityprotection_set_fake_login_cookies' ) ) :
    function securityprotection_set_fake_login_cookies() { // set fake login cookies

        $expiration = time() + 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS;
        $expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        $secure = '';

        // login cookie names are located in wp-includes/default-constants.php:
        // define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_' . COOKIEHASH);
        // define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'wordpress_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH);

        $cookie_name_random = securityprotection_random_string_generator();
        $cookie_value_random = securityprotection_random_string_generator();
        $auth_cookie_fake = 'wordpress_'.$cookie_name_random;
        $logged_in_cookie_fake = 'wordpress_logged_in_'.$cookie_name_random;

        setcookie($auth_cookie_fake, $cookie_value_random, $expire, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true);
        setcookie($logged_in_cookie_fake, $cookie_value_random, $expire, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true);
    }
endif; // end of securityprotection_set_fake_login_cookies()
```

Link to the plugin - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025327/share/security-protection-1.2.zip

Comment: Define "proper"? :) There are very few things for which "proper" hook is set in stone. Does it work for you? Do you have any specific concerns about this implementation?

Comment: @Rarst It does not work for me because I add redirect to 'login_init' hook and it works on registration page too and that is why I am asking about it.

Comment: Please go back, file an [edit], add all the needed info and show your current code.

Comment: @kaiser thank you very much for your help. I added the code to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper hooks for login and register actions:

```
<?php
function custom_plugin_hooks() {
    add_action( 'login_form', 'custom_plugin_form_inputs' );
    add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_plugin_login_check', 100, 3 );
    add_action( 'register_form', 'custom_plugin_form_inputs' );
    add_action( 'register_post', 'custom_plugin_registration_check', 100, 3);
}
custom_plugin_hooks();

function custom_plugin_form_inputs() {
    echo "\n".'<p>';
    echo '<label>Custom input: <br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="custom-input" class="input" value="" />';
    echo '</label></p>'."\n";
}

function custom_plugin_login_check($user, $username, $password) {
    // user gave us valid username and password
    if( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
            if( $_POST['custom-input'] !== 'custom-value' ) {
                $error = new WP_Error();
                $error->add( 'custom-login-error', 'Login error.');
                return $error;
            }
        }
    }
    return $user;
}

function custom_plugin_registration_check( $login, $email, $errors ) {
    if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        if( $_POST['custom-input'] !== 'custom-value' ) {
            $errors->add( 'custom-registration-error', 'Registration error.');
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
?>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding at least two lines of text or some comments in code to explain _why_ this is snippets are helpful?